# Recursive function that divides the number by 2 without using /

Tags: function, recursion, division

I need help.
I need to create a recursive function that receives a "n" number and returns "n/2" without dividing.

Edit :

This is what I wrote, but it works only if after dividing it will still be a decimal number and not a float, that's why I asked.

```
int recursive(int a, int b)
{ 
  if ( a == (0.5 * b) )
    return a;

  return recursive(a-1, b);
}
```

Comment: Well, if you're working with strictly integer division, you could use a "right shift" operator. For C-style languages, this is denoted by `>>`. This function works: `f (n) = n >> 1`. Notice that this isn't recursive. (Why would it need to be? This is more efficient.)

Comment: What you have done please share first that its not "DO MY WORK SITE"

Comment: I know it is not, it's just that they ask me to do it recursively, and the way I tried didn't work so I went out for help :/

Answer (score 0):

Recursive solutions are much slower, but here's an implementation for positive integers using python 3

```
def divRecursive(a,b):
    if a<b:
        return 0
    return 1+divRecursive(a-b,b)
```

Comment: And btw simonzack what you did there has nothing to do with what I asked O.o

Comment: You're right Dollery, I did Boris's homework and didn't even get any thanks. I've learnt my lesson.

Comment: Cause it wasn't even close to what I need, it gives some non related output, but still thanks