# Recursive function divide a number

Tags: c, recursion, divide

I need to create a recursive function that receives a number by two without using `/`.

This is what I wrote, but it works only if after dividing it will still be a decimal number and not a float, that's why I asked.

```
int recursive(int a, int b){
  if ( a == (0.5 * b) )
    return a;
  return recursive(a-1, b);
}
```

Btw, the function can receive only 1 parameter not 2 or more :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recursive function that divides the number by 2 without using /](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996342/recursive-function-that-divides-the-number-by-2-without-using)

Comment: I know, but if no one reopens me the post, or helps me, what am I supposed to do??

Comment: Edit your previous question to make it clearer. I'm not sure I understand the part about floats up there. Do not repost your questions.

Comment: essentially you would like to make a `float dividebytwo (float a)` function without using `/`, correct?

Comment: That's what I did, and it needs to be decimal so nope no float.

Comment: I see "int recursive(int a, int b)" what does it mean "he wants a float"? @Taylor so please get rid of your downvoting

Comment: I see a really negative feedback from this community :/

Comment: @BorisWainstein That's probably because you're asking people to do your homework for you and also reposted the exact same question that was closed 2 hours ago as "not a real question".

Comment: If this is not a question then what is a question? looks like I've arrived to the wrong planet.

Comment: If you want a function that takes one argument 'n', then why write a function that takes two arguments, 'a' and 'b'?

Comment: @j883376 And I'm not asking them to do my homework, I do it because I am having trouble, and I just can't get to understand how to do it.... even some tips would come good (If they are correct for sure).
Looks like that when I felt that this would be the page to get help in case needed, etc in programming I came to totally the wrong place, so what is this page supposed to be then?

Comment: @BorisWainstein you've explained your problem very poorly, making it hard to impossible for anyone to give you a satisfactory answer. I literally have no idea what you're asking for.

Comment: Homework problem, hmm?

Comment: Are you sure it can only recieve 1 parameters? If this is some kind of a homework, teaching recursion with codes that that is not completely encapsulated is usually counterproductive.

Comment: @Anonymous Believe me I have no idea neither. And I'm really sorry for all the trouble caused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, it should work:

```
int dividebytwo (int a){
    static int answer = 0;

    if (a < 0){
        if ((answer * 2) > a){
            answer --;
            return dividebytwo (a);
        }

        return answer;

    } else if (a > 0){
        if ((answer * 2) < a){
            answer ++;
            return dividebytwo (a);
        }

        return answer;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The trick here is using the `static` attribute. The static attribute means that the variable is only initialized once and retains its value after every function call. Really, you're using two parameters but it looks like you're only using one.

The only downside to this function is that you can only count on it to work more than once. Since this is probably for a simple homework assignment, it probably doesn't matter. But in reality, this is considered hugely inefficient and unreliable.

To compensate for the `only-works-once` factor, may add one of these fixes:

- declare `answer` as a global variable and set it to `0` before every function call.
- append `return answer = 0;` to the end of the function, instead of `return 0;`. This is so that whenever you want to call it again, you would call it beforehand as `dividebytwo (0);`.

I also cannot stress enough how weird of a concept this is, it sets of all sorts of red flags for anyone who practices careful programming - could be why you're getting so many downvotes. So use with caution!

Comment: but with every --/++ the static answer will change, and if you don't write the static it will work too.

Comment: try taking out `static` and see what happens, you will get a stack overflow. So no, it will not work without `static`. Also, I've added some info in my answer you should read.

Comment: It's not me who puts the rules xD

Answer (score 2):

I think you need something like this

```
int divide(int a, int b){
   if(a - b <= 0){
      return 1;
   }
   else {
      return divide(a - b, b) + 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but please read closely:
returns "n/2" without dividing

And it can receive only 1 parameter.

Comment: I see "int recursive(int a, int b)" what does it mean "he wants a float"? @Taylor

Comment: I think one solution could be to find a series which converges to n/2 given n...there should be one but I don't remember.

Comment: I had thought he wanted a `float` value when he said `decimal`, but the down-vote is also because he mentioned he only wanted `one` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This divides by two using repeated subtraction and recursion.

```
int divide_by_two(int a) {
    if (a < 0) return -divide_by_two(-a);
    if (a < 2) return 0;
    return 1 + divide_by_two(a - 2);
}
```

Generalising, this divides `a` by `b` using repeated subtraction and recursion.

```
int divide(int a, int b) {
    if (a < 0) return -divide(-a, b);
    if (b < 0) return -divide(a, -b);
    if (a < b) return 0;
    return 1 + divide(a - b, b);
}
```

Note, these functions don't round exactly the same way that division is defined to do in C.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int divide(int a, int b){
    if( a-b < 0)
      return 0;
    else if ( a-b == 0)
      return 1;
    else {
      return divide(a-b, b) + 1;
    }
  }
```

http://codepad.org/o4CoiaON